# displaying join table information with a solr result in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, has-many-through, sunspot

I have a collection of Fabrics each Fabric has many colours.

My DB association
Fabric has_many Colours through Fabric_colours

I am using solr to index my Fabrics, so structuring complex SQL queries is not possible.

The join model Fabric_colours, holds
fabric_id
colour_id
percentage

The Colours model holds the hex value of each Colour.

I would like to display in my view,

each colour present in a said fabric,
the percentage in which said Colour is present

My view is loading dozens of fabrics at a time and I do not want to perform additional queries to get this information.  It was my understanding that Solr has pulled all of the associated table’s data into a single ‘document’ so this should not be necessary.

At present in my _fabric partial i have the following code showing the colours present in that fabric.

```
    <% fabric.colours.each do |c| %>
        <%= c.hex %>
    <% end%>
```

how would i call the the specific join table entry linking the fabric, and that specific colour, to extract the percentage?

Answer (score 0):

Solr can store data inside its index so it won't hit the database when you want to display the data. I recommend you the [sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) gem that will you to achieve this. Checkout its wiki, especially the [Setting up classes for search and indexing](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Setting-up-classes-for-search-and-indexing) section where it is described.

Be aware that this way leads to data doubling - you will have the same data stored in the database and in the solr index.

Instead of storing data in solr index I advise you to use eager loading. You can preload colour percentages and also the color objects in the controller.

```
def show
  # Loads fabrics, the join table and colours
  @fabrics = Fabric.includes(:fabric_colours => [:colour])... # .all or .where or whatever
end

def search
  # Searches for fabrics with eager loading
  search = Fabric.search(:include => { :fabric_colours => :colour }) do
    # ... search criteria
  end
  @fabrics = search.results
end
```

If this is still slow for you, use caching.